# Is there a structured source of Holland Code (RIASEC) data available?

Tags: database

I'm trying to put together some career-related resources and I need access to the Holland Codes/RIASEC that classifies interests and skills to occupations.  I can find many sites that already do this, but I can't find raw data in a structured format.  Is anyone aware of a source for this.  It can be commercial with licensing fees, though free would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I figured it out!  It turns out that the data is free to download and use from O*NET (http://www.onetcenter.org/).  You can get ASCII data files, Access, FoxPro, and other formats.  It looks like this is what I need.